# Adobe AIR - GPU render mode - low FPS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, gpu, frame-rate

I have an Android game created with Flash CS6 and AIR and I am trying to use the GPU render mode.

My Samsung Tab 2 10" is showing FPS of ~20 compared to a Prestigio Tab 8 HD which is showing ~47 FPS. That's when playing the game.

So I wanted to see what FPS I get using a simple blank Adobe AIR app that does nothing and doesn't contain anything and the results were surprising: the Tab 2 plays at ~35 FPS and the Prestigio at ~57 FPS.

Obviously, if I only get ~35 FPS with a blank app in GPU mode on the Samsung Tab 2, who know what FPS I would get on other tabs...

Is there an explanation for this and is there something I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to this previous question. It details a lot of things that can cause lag. Also note that Samsung devices generally run slower, at least in my testing, due to the amount of default background processes Samsung has running. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934966/adobe-air-lag-on-high-resolution-android-devices/21999691#21999691

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not running into power save mode on your Galaxy tab 2.
When you enable the power save mode you will get lower FPS, but in normal mode you should get the same FPS (or relativlly close to each others).

**Update**

I have created a project that show the FPS used by the application you can download source code from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6AXcHv0-kyTSURUcXprVlI5b1k/edit?usp=sharing) or APK file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6AXcHv0-kyTU29uanFTbU9CcVE/edit?usp=sharing).

i test it on my machine and it give 60 FPS, also Radu tested it on tab2 and it gives 60 FPS.

i am using FB 4.6, i used `direct` `render mode` and set the `FrameRate` to `60`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem, power save mode is disabled. Any other ideas?

Comment: mmmm wired, one last idea use direct rendering mode adobe recommend it for mobiles.

Comment: I am getting around 30-35 fps on all devices with direct. GPU is my first option because I have >50 on most devices I tested. I just need to figure out what the problem is with my Tab 2.

Comment: In Flash Builder 4.6 we have parameter called FrameRate, it is by default 25 and you can increase it to 60, i am sure you have such option in CS6.
the drawing quality in direct is much better than gpu (vector drawing).

Comment: The app is set at 60 fps. The question is why it only works at ~35 FPS when it's a blank app.

Comment: can you share your apk to give it a test on my device?

Comment: is there a place where I can send you the apk? I wouldn't like to make it public right now.

Comment: I've been doing some work on my game and been converting all texts to bitmaps (including the dynamic textfields) and now I am getting ~28 FPS (+8 FPS improvement) on my Samsung Tab 2 using GPU render mode when doing a specific animation. Less complex animations are generally playing at around ~33 FPS. However, the other devices I have (HTC Explorer, HTC  One X and Prestigio Tab 8 HD) all run with at least 40 FPS when doing the same animation.

Comment: i was talking about the blank app apk, it should give 60 FPS (so i want to test it on my device), anyway this is my email anas.tamemy@gmail.com